# Reinstalled Windows 8.1 Toolbar and Buttons Too Small and Strange Font

Tags: fonts, windows-8.1, toolbar, appearance

I recently had to reinstall my Windows 8.1 on my laptop.  But now, the font looks wrong and way too light-colored.  I think it's Courier New and should have been something like Calibri.  Also, the toolbar buttons are unusually small.  I've pasted three images to demonstrate (but the real effect is not completely evident on StackOverflow).  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

EDIT: some add'l info - Windows 8.1, Lenovo Yoga 2 Pro, 3200x1800 resolution.

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Does this have anything to do with programming?

Comment: It might prevent me from better programming as it affects my IDE's, too.  :)  But, I acknowledge your point.

Comment: It could be argued this is on topic, but I'd say it's more relevant on Super User.

Comment: Ok, posted the topic there (id: 1152811).  http://superuser.com/questions/1152811/reinstalled-windows-8-1-toolbar-and-buttons-too-small-and-strange-font